# How to Count Unique Dates for a Given Year in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have a list of dates in Column A of Excel as follows (header is cell A1):

```
Date
3/3/2015
3/10/2015
3/10/2015
4/15/2015
4/10/2016
4/29/2016
4/29/2016
5/5/2017
5/5/2017
6/7/2017
11/11/2017
2/3/2018
```

In column B, I have my target year (header in B1, value in B2):

```
Target Year
2017
```

I would like to count the number of unique dates in column A that are in the target year. If I use `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A13,A2:A13))`, then I get the number of unique dates in the list (9). How do I extend this logic to add the condition of only dates in the target year (result should be 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the criteria to the numerator:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A2:A13)=2017)/COUNTIF(A2:A13,A2:A13))
```

If the year does not equal 2017 then the numerator becomes `0` and will not add to the total.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this array formula also:*

[image]

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(YEAR($A$2:$A$10)=B$2,IF($A$2:$A$10<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0))),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))}
```

**Note,**

- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.
- Finish the formula with *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.